# How can I solve this Error and why it occured?

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, angular-material-7

Implementing **AngularMaterial** Table with sorting headers I'm getting this Error in console:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined
    at

and this Error in Terminal:

error TS2740: Type 'MatTableDataSource' is missing the following properties from type 'Employee[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.

error TS2322: Type 'MatSort' is not assignable to type '(compareFn?: (a: Employee, b: Employee) => number) => Employee[]'.

Type 'MatSort' provides no match for the signature '(compareFn?: (a: Employee, b: Employee) => number): Employee[]'.

I cannot get what it wants from me. I would appreciate any hints!

I've used the code from AngularMaterial Documentation except for an interface for Data. Can this be an issue?

EmployeeListComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { EmployeeService } from '../shared/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['fullname', 'position', 'mobile'];
  dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private service: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(employees => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(employees);
      console.log(this.dataSource);
    });
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

  }

}
```

EmployeeList HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="fullname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Full Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fullname}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Position </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="mobile">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Mobile </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mobile}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

EmployeeService

```
getEmployees() {
    return this.firestore.collection<Employee>('employees')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data } as Employee;
       })
        )
      );
}
```

Employee Class

```
export class Employee {
  id: string;
  fullname: string;
  empCode: string;
  position: string;
  mobile: string;
}
```

Comment: You can try setting a timeout for the sort operation till the data is fetched, by adding `setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.sort= this.sort);` inside the **ngOnInit** after the **console.log** line.

Comment: Did the `setTimeout()` work.?

Comment: @Karthik_Siddh I've solved the problem with _ngAfterViewInit_ and moved some code into a subscribe section. It worked for me well what solved the problem with Errors but my sorting still doesn't work for some reasons. Maybe you know why? I would appreciate any hints on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access data from outside the subscription, it should be inside.

After this you will run into trouble with `this.sort` being undefined in within the `ngOnInit` hook, this occurs because you are trying to access a HTMLelement that has not yet been draw. (MatSort)

There is a lifecycle hook you can use to ensure that the view is ready to be accessed by the @ViewChild, this is ngAfterViewInit, only is only fired when the HTML is drawn.

Try structuring like so.

---

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { EmployeeService } from '../shared/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['fullname', 'position', 'mobile'];
  dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private service: EmployeeService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void
  {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(employees => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(employees);
      if (this.sort) // check it is defined.
      {
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Documentation [AfterViewInit Lifecycle](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) // [More details](https://www.cuelogic.com/blog/angular-lifecycle).

Comment: Thanks! It helped with the Error but my sorting still doesn’t work :/  I’ve already compared everything to the original code from the documentation - everything is the same. What can be a problem?

Comment: im not 100% with material bits just offering my help with the more angular related errors. Does you data match what the mat sort is expecting ?

Comment: I guess so  it builds up my table with the data I have. AngularMaterial requires an Array with data. I’ve got it. Can the reason be of using an Employee class except for Employee interface? That’s the only difference which I can see. I’ve used all the tags matSort on mat-table, and may-sort-header on mat-header-cell

Comment: please edit in your data to the question and the shape of the class you have defined will take a look

Comment: My bad! :D I should have imported MatSortModule into my module. I've examined the documentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Overall you code looks Okay, but this line

```
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

is in wrong place , it should be placed inside `subscribe` block.

**Reason** for `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined`

You are mxing your synchronous code with asynchronous and by that I mean that your `subscribe` code will only execute when the response from API is returned (1 to 2 sec) but  `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;` will not wait for response because it's synchronous code and it'll continue its execution regardless of any `HTTP` request and your `dataSource` object will be `undefined` so you need to shift it in asynchronous part.

Your code would be like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(employees => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(employees);
      console.log(this.dataSource);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; <- note this line 

   });   
}
```